# Simulate a4 page in html PHP LOOP

Tags: php, loops

I want to create a loop that when it reaches 20th, just create a new page, then, again a new page and so until the cycle is done.

I have 5rows 4 columns (5x4 = 20 labels per page)

The peculiarity is that I have four prices and the number of labels depends on the total number. I give an example.
I have **columns broi, price1, price2, price3, price4**
With sample data:

> broi: 90
>
> price1: 4.85
>
> price2: 7.90
>
> price3: 9.30
>
> price4: 11.10

We divide **(broi)90/4** and we get that from 1 price we have to have 22.5, for example:

> price1: 4,85 - 22pcs
>
> price2: 7.90 - 24pcs
>
> price3: 9.30 - 22pcs
>
> price4: 11.10 - 22pcs
> (total pcs 90 = broi)

Here's an example, by way of a snapshot,
[image: to now]

And I want to be:
[image: want to be]

My php code is:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
   exit();
}
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

/* разделяме на 4 и правиме второто число да компенсира остатъка */
function calculate_columns(int $total, int $size, int $prefer = 1): array {
    $columns = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $columns[$i] = floor($total / $size);
    }
    $columns[$prefer] += $total - $columns[$prefer] * $size;
    return $columns;
    /*
     Array ( 
         [0] => 22 
         [1] => 24 
         [2] => 22 
         [3] => 22 
     ) 
     */
}
?><html>
    <head>
        <style>body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  //box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
page[size="A4"] {  
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm; 
}
page[size="A4"][layout="landscape"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  height: 21cm;  
}
page[size="A3"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  height: 42cm;
}
page[size="A3"][layout="landscape"] {
  width: 42cm;
  height: 29.7cm;  
}
page[size="A5"] {
  width: 14.8cm;
  height: 21cm;
}
page[size="A5"][layout="landscape"] {
  width: 21cm;
  height: 14.8cm;  
}
@media print {
  body, page {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}

/* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left:10px;
  color: #000 ;
  font-size:19px !important;
  font-weight: bold; font: arial;
}

/* Centered text */
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-left:6px;
  
}


.A4 {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

@media print {
  .page-break {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  size: A4 portrait;
}

@media print {
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .A4 {
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  .noprint {
    display: none;
  }
  .enable-print {
    display: block;
  }
}


</style>
<script>
  //window.print();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$lstoutput = array();
$sqlquery = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=1");
while($row = $sqlquery->fetch_array()) {
    $lstoutput[] = $row;
}
    $labels = calculate_columns($lstoutput[0]['broi'], 4);
        $page_much = $lstoutput[0]['broi']/20; //$labels[0]
        $page_number = '0';
        for(; $page_number < $page_much ; $page_number++){
            echo '<page size="A4"><table cellpadding="6" style="padding-top: 30px"><tbody>';
            if($lstoutput[0]['price1'] != null) {
                $labels_number = 0;
                for ($labels_number = 0; $labels_number <= $labels[0]; $labels_number++) {
                    if ($labels_number %4 === 0) {
                        echo("</tr>\n<tr style='margin:1px'>");
                    }
                    echo '<td style="margin:1px" class="container"><img src="label.png" alt="label" style="border:1px solid #333;width:184px;height:184px" /><div class="centered">'.$lstoutput[0]['price1'].'</div></td>';
                }
            }
            if($lstoutput[0]['price2'] != null) {
                $labels_number = 0;
                for ($labels_number = 0; $labels_number <= $labels[0]; $labels_number++) {
                    if ($labels_number %4 === 0) {
                        echo("</tr>\n<tr style='margin:1px'>");
                    }
                    echo '<td style="margin:1px" class="container"><img src="label.png" alt="label" style="border:1px solid #333;width:184px;height:184px" /><div class="centered">'.$lstoutput[0]['price2'].'</div></td>';
                }
            }
            echo '</tbody></table></page>';
        }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to look into the [break-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after) css property.

Comment: No, CSS did not fix the problem. I think the error is in my logic but I do not know exactly where.

Comment: based on 1) having done something similar (though not as complex) and 2) not understanding the code particularly well, a suggestion: do not handle the page breaking in the php (that looks like the purpose of the `for page_number` loop). Instead, let `@media print` styling handle it.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the labels as divs with css `display: inline-block` instead of using a table, the browser itself will reflow the elements to fit on each page.

```css
.label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="label">label</div>
<div class="label">label</div>
<div class="label">label</div>
<div class="label">label</div>
<div class="label">label</div>
...
```

This looks as this in my preview window:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @solarc, but don't working for my code. I don't understand why my code not working :/

Answer (score 0):

@DinoCoderSaurus I set the code after I removed the cycle to create the number of pages, added the **page-break-after** function (css) but did not get it again, set the photo + code.

```
   table { page-break-inside:auto }
   tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
```

[image]

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'USER', 'PASS', 'DATABASE');
/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
   exit();
}
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

/* разделяме на 4 и правиме второто число да компенсира остатъка */
function calculate_columns(int $total, int $size, int $prefer = 1): array {
    $columns = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $columns[$i] = floor($total / $size);
    }
    $columns[$prefer] += $total - $columns[$prefer] * $size;
    return $columns;
    /*
     Array ( 
         [0] => 22 
         [1] => 24 
         [2] => 22 
         [3] => 22 
     ) 
     */
}
?><html>
    <head>
        <style>body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  //box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
page[size="A4"] {  
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm; 
}
page[size="A4"][layout="landscape"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  height: 21cm;  
}
page[size="A3"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  height: 42cm;
}
page[size="A3"][layout="landscape"] {
  width: 42cm;
  height: 29.7cm;  
}
page[size="A5"] {
  width: 14.8cm;
  height: 21cm;
}
page[size="A5"][layout="landscape"] {
  width: 21cm;
  height: 14.8cm;  
}
@media print {
  body, page {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}

/* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left:10px;
  color: #000 ;
  font-size:19px !important;
  font-weight: bold; font: arial;
}

/* Centered text */
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-left:6px;

}


.A4 {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

@media print {
  .page-break {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  size: A4 portrait;
}

@media print {
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .A4 {
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  .noprint {
    display: none;
  }
  .enable-print {
    display: block;
  }
}

   table { page-break-inside:auto }
   tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }

</style>
<script>
  //window.print();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$lstoutput = array();
$sqlquery = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=1");
while($row = $sqlquery->fetch_array()) {
    $lstoutput[] = $row;
}
    $labels = calculate_columns($lstoutput[0]['broi'], 4);
            echo '<page size="A4"><table cellpadding="5" style="padding-top: 10px"><tbody>';
            if($lstoutput[0]['price1'] != null) {
                $labels_number = 0;
                for ($labels_number = 0; $labels_number <= $labels[0]; $labels_number++) {
                    if ($labels_number %4 === 0) {
                        echo("</tr>\n<tr style='margin:1px'>");
                    }
                    echo '<td style="margin:1px" class="container"><img src="label.png" alt="label" style="border:1px solid #000;width:90%;height:90%" /><div class="centered">'.$lstoutput[0]['price1'].'</div></td>';
                }
            }
            if($lstoutput[0]['price2'] != null) {
                $labels_number = 0;
                for ($labels_number = 0; $labels_number <= $labels[1]; $labels_number++) {
                    if ($labels_number %4 === 0) {
                        echo("</tr>\n<tr style='margin:1px'>");
                    }
                    echo '<td style="margin:1px" class="container"><img src="label.png" alt="label" style="border:1px solid #000;width:90%;height:90%" /><div class="centered">'.$lstoutput[0]['price2'].'</div></td>';
                }
            }
            echo '</tbody></table></page>';
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might need to remove the table and use divs instead. Actually, if you only use divs, you don't really need to do anything special. I'll write an answer with that approach.

Comment: The label counter should not be per price, it should be per label. Add 1 to the counter after each label and when `counter % 4 == 0`, close the table row.